# Paypal Rest API - Live site - Can get access token but 401 making get requests

Tags: paypal

I have successfully created an application to pull payment data from paypal using their rest api and upload it to a reporting system. Everything works fine in my sandbox but when I try to go live I get the following:

```
I, [2013-07-20T14:16:08.728841 #2]  INFO -- : Request[post]: https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token 
I, [2013-07-20T14:16:09.615933 #2]  INFO -- : Response[200]: OK, Duration: 0.887s
I, [2013-07-20T14:16:09.644345 #2]  INFO -- : Request[get]: https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment
I, [2013-07-20T14:16:10.263650 #2]  INFO -- : Response[401]: Unauthorized, Duration: 0.618s
I, [2013-07-20T14:16:10.263968 #2]  INFO -- : Request[post]: https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token
I, [2013-07-20T14:16:11.026994 #2]  INFO -- : Response[200]: OK, Duration: 0.763s
I, [2013-07-20T14:16:11.027277 #2]  INFO -- : Request[get]: https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment
I, [2013-07-20T14:16:11.595411 #2]  INFO -- : Response[401]: Unauthorized, Duration: 0.568s
```

So it looks like my credentials are correct as I get a 200 when requesting my token but I get a 401 when trying to get payment data. Why is that?

I am not in the US and I know that processing payments is currently only available in the US but I am not processing payments just retrieving payment data.

Lil' help!

Comment: when you do the token request (/v1/oauth2/token) - in the response you would see a parameter called "scope" along with the access token. 
Ex. "scope":"https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.*"

Can you check what values you see ?

Comment: @Praveen thanks for the reply. Using the ruby api I get the following:
    `$ @api.token_hash[:scope]` 
    `=> "openid"`

Does 'openid' sound right?

Comment: 'openid' sounds right if you are using an application configured to use the Login with PayPal capability. If you've selected "Payment" capability too - then you should see other scopes like the ones I mentioned in my previous comment above. So please login to developer.paypal.com and make sure you application was setup for live transactions.

Comment: @Praveen It looks like my application is set up correctly. in the sense I only have 'accept payments' not 'log in with paypal' as the capabilities selected. Any ideas?

Comment: @Praveen, it sounds like since I have payments enabled and have a non US account you can't even pull payment data for reporting purposes. Does that sound possible to you?

Comment: yes that's right - if you have a non-US account, you can't use the APIs even for reporting purposes since we don't set the API scopes unless you qualify for the product (which is currently offered to US users only).

Comment: @Praveen thanks, you have been very helpful. I guess the last question is do you know when they will roll it out to Australia?

Comment: very very soon :-) (seriously though - I can't give out the dates but it's coming)

Comment: I got 401 error on live. I am able to create card token but when i try to execute the payment. It show me message like unauthorized payment. Working fine on sandbox.

Is it something to do with future payment API. Because in sandbox all API permission is enable. while in live future payment and payout not. Is anything you can do for me??